# Objects as arguments

Tags: java

I try to:

- Create a `Car` object in the `Main`.
- Send the object as an argument to the `carOwners` class.
- Print the entire `carOwners` data from main.

`Name` and `Address` will be printed, but not the `Car`.

What is wrong with my code?

```
public class TestProgram {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Car Saab = createCar();
        carOwners guy = createCarOwners (Saab);
        printAll(guy);
    }

    public static Car createCar (){
        //user input a, b, c, d
        Car temporary = new Car (a, b, c, d);
        return temporary;
    }
    public static carOwners createCarOwners (Car x){
        //user input a, b
        Car c = x;
        carOwners temporary = new carOwners (a, b, c);
        return temporary;
    }

    public static void printAll (carOwners x){
        x.printCarData();
        x.printNameAddress();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Car {
    private String model;
    private String Year;
    private String licensePlate;
    private String color;

    public Car (String x, int y, String z, String q){
        model = x;
        Year = y;
        licensePlate = z;
        color = q;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class carOwners {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Car TheCar;

    public carOwners (String n, String a, Car b){
        name = n;
        address = a;
        TheCar = b;
    }

    public void printNameAddress(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(address);
    }

    public void printCarData(){
        System.out.println(TheCar);
    }
}
```

Comment: You pass *references to Objects* to other methods.

Comment: Override `Object#toString` in your `Car` class.

Comment: You should get into the habit of giving your variables meaningful names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is here:

```
public void printCarData(){
        System.out.println(TheCar);
    }
```

You want to print an Object. That doens't work because Java uses the toString-Method for that. If you want to do it like that you have to override the toString()-Method of your car class like that:

```
public String toString()
{
     return "CarModel: " + this.model + ", Production Year: " + year;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

override `toString()`, so you can custom the output format of `Car`

```
public String toString(){
    return "Model :" + this.model + ",Year :" + year;
}
```